# Why can't I use register here?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, 32-bit

Why it doesn't print the character if I use register instead of at memory?

here's code:

```
mov eax,97
mov ebp,eax
call print_char

print_char:
pusha          
mov eax,4       
mov ebx,1       
mov ecx,ebp 
mov edx,1       
int 80h         
popa            
ret
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not that you can't use a register... it's that you're not providing the address a string (specifically a C-string, a null-terminated<sup>1</sup> array of characters).

Quick background info for those unfamiliar with [`int 80h` system calls](http://int80h.org/) on linux, here is the [calling convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535989/what-are-the-calling-conventions-for-unix-linux-system-calls-on-x86-64) on x86:

```
System call #  - eax
Parameters     - ebx, ecx, edx, esi, edi, ebp
```

So, [you're calling system call 4](http://asm.sourceforge.net/syscall.html), which is `sys_write`.  The C signature is:

```
ssize_t sys_write(unsigned int fd, const char * buf, size_t count)
```

You can see that the second parameter (`ecx`) is supposed to be a `const char* buf`, which is a pointer to a string.  You're passing `97`, which is certainly not a valid address, and you're probably seg-faulting.

A quick-and-dirty method for your example, which uses the stack to store that one-character string:

```
print_char:    # Takes char in ebp
    pusha
    mov    eax, 4     # sys_write
    mov    ebx, 1     # stdout

    push   ebp
    mov    ecx, esp   # buf  (char on stack)

    mov    edx, 1     # just one character
    int    80h        # linux syscall
    pop    ebp
    popa
    ret
```

This should print the letter 'a' (ASCII 97) to stdout.  If you wanted to print a decimal 97, then just like in C, where you'd be calling something from the `printf` family, you need to convert that decimal number to a string before trying to write it to `stdout`.

---

<sub>1 - Technically the string doesn't need to be null-terminated here since you can specify printing just one character.</sub>